# Make a Java class work as a sequence in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, sequence, clojure-java-interop

I am using a Java class that represents a sequence of results (somewhat like a Clojure vector).

I would like to use this class with the typical Clojure sequence functions (i.e. I want to have the class behave as if it supported the sequence abstraction) however I **can't change the class** so am unable to make it implement `clojure.lang.Seqable` or similar. Also, annoyingly, the class does not implement `java.util.Collection` or `java.lang.Iterable`.

I can see a few options:

- Use `iterator-seq` on the object's (existing) iterator.
- Wrap the object in another class that implements `java.util.Collection` / `clojure.lang.Sequable`
- Create a function that builds a Clojure vector or sequence by querying the Object

Are there any other options? What is the best approach?

Comment: `iterator-seq` seems to be fine, internally it does the same thing as your second point about wrapping the object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest and most straightforward would be to use `iterator-seq`.

This does beg the question:  Why doesn't core Clojure provide a protocol like SeqSource that would be called by `seq`.  Then non-standard collections could be "extended" to supply a seq, similar to how the InternalReduce works for `reduce`.

Comment: Because seq is (a) used by the compiler, and thus needs to be java-friendly (ie an interface), and also (b) called very, very often, so that it needs to be as fast as possible - protocols are faster than a lot of things, but not as fast as a simple interface dispatch.

Comment: @amalloy  then maybe a `to-seq` function instead

Comment: "Also, annoyingly, the class does not implement java.util.Collection or java.lang.Iterable."

Comment: @noahz But, from the original question,  "object's (existing) iterator" implies there is an iterator available. Given this is seems overkill to create a proxy.  Were there not an iterator, then of course some other method would be possible

Comment: Adding a function called `to-seq` that does the same thing as `seq` doesn't solve any problems at all. It still needs to be accessible to the compiler, which of course no clojure functions are.

Comment: @amalloy - What I should of said was a protocol SeqSource that has one function, to-seq, that could then be implemented on any arbitrary class thus allowing any class to participate in the seq paradigm.

Answer (score 6):

[Use `proxy`](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Implementing%20Interfaces%20and%20Extending%20Classes) to extend the class and make it implement `ISeq`

Answer (score 2):

My first shot would be to create lazy-seq of that object:

```
(defn sequify [obj]
  (letfn [(inner [idx] 
                 (when (< idx (.size obj))
                          (cons (.get obj idx)
                                (lazy-seq 
                                  (inner (inc idx))))))]
    (inner 0)))
```

Just replace `.size` and `.get` with appropriate methods.

Writing a wrapper may be more appropriate if you want to improve performance compared to `lazy-seq` solution.